# F# Constructor Override

Tags: c#, swift, constructor, f#, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to convert the following Swift code to F#:

```
class BaseCell: UICollectionViewCell {
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

I have seen that in C# this can be done as follows:

```
 public class BaseCell : UICollectionViewCell
{

    [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
    public BaseCell (CGRect frame) : base (frame)
    {

    }
```

and I have obtained the following in F#:

```
[<Register ("BaseCell")>]
type BaseCell (handle: IntPtr) as this = 
    inherit UICollectionViewCell (handle)
```

however, I'm not sure how to proceed with the constructor override.